# Identifying Directories Not Tracked by Repo Manifest in Android Project, Including Manually Cloned Git Repos

Tags: android, git, git-repo

I'm working on an Android project that uses the Repo tool to manage Git repositories.

In my project, I have a mix of directories that are tracked by Repo (i.e., they are in the Repo manifest), Git repositories that were manually cloned and thus are not tracked by Repo, and directories that are not associated with any Git repository.

The whole thing is a mess, and I'm trying to clean it up.

I am trying to find a method that will effectively find all directories that are not listed in the Repo manifest.

This includes both Git repositories that have been manually cloned and non-Git directories.

I'm planning to write a specialized tool to accomplish this, but before I do, I'd like to see if there is a more straightforward method involving shell command magic that will work.